# Create multiple plots with multiple lines on each from a Data Frame in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a couple of data frames that may be of relevance - the first looks like:

```
> colnames(newData)
[1] "Date"   "Site"   "Test_Group" "Revenue"
```

The second looks like:

```
> colnames(filterData)
[1] "Site" "Date" "Test_1"   "Test_2"
```

and was created by running:
`z <- dcast(newData, Site + Date ~ Test_Group, sum)`

Where Test_1 and Test_2 are the levels of Test_Group in the first data frame (newData).

What I'm aiming to do is have as many graphs as I have sites - each graph with date along the x-axis, revenue on the y-axis and two lines, one for each test group.

So far, I've been able to generate one of the graph I want by doing:

```
one_site <- newData[newData$Site == "one_site",]
ggplot(one_site, aes(one_site$Date, one_site$Revenue, colour=as.factor(one_site$Test_Group), group = as.factor(one_site$Test_Group))) + geom_line()
```

I'm wondering if there's a way to achieve this result without using a for loop.

*edit:*

Have investigated facet wraps and they seem to be a step in the right direction - however, running the following query:

```
ggplot(newData,aes(newData$Date, newData$Revenue, colour=as.factor(newData$Test_Group), group=as.factor(newData$Test_Group))) 
 + geom_line(aes(group=newData$Test_Group, colour=newData$Test_Group)) + 
 + facet_wrap( ~ Site, scales="free", ncol = 3)
```

I get the required number of graphs and graphs with the required axes and titles. The legend also shows the titles of the time series to be Test_1 and Test_2. However, looking at the graphs, there is only one line plotted for each of the graphs - either Test_1 or Test_2! I don't really understand why this is - the only think I can think of is a possible sorting issue where R requires data that is grouped together to be next to each other in a data frame? Beyond that, I'm baffled!

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: Don't subset your data and use `facet_wrap` or `facet_grid`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Make multiple separate plots from single data frame in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873419/make-multiple-separate-plots-from-single-data-frame-in-r)

Comment: @krlmlr I actually don't think it's a duplicate as that question deals with (unless I misunderstood it) with multiple plots, each with multiple graphs on, with each of the graphs featuring a single time-series. I'm asking about one plot, with multiple graphs, with each graph featuring multiple time series.

Comment: As it is, I'm currently investigation suggestions by @Roland and they're looking good :)

Comment: @Roland I've tried using facet_grid and have updated the question above to reflect my results on this - any idea? Thanks, Matt

Comment: First of all, remove `newData$` from all `aes`. Secondly, provide a reproducible example and people can help you better.